# query string on link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In a `GridView` I have the list of 2 bed and breakfasts (ShowAllBeb.aspx) which are in DB, one with `idname = 0` and the other with `idname = 1`. I've created `LinkButton`s that will refer to the B&B detail (DisplayBeb.aspx)

Code aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' 
  ForeColor="#0066cc" 
  PostBackUrl='<%# "~/site/DisplayBeb.aspx?idname={0}" + Eval("name")  %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

code aspx.cs:

```
using (dcDataContext dc = new dcDataContext())
            {
                DataListBeb.DataSource = from beb in dc.beb
                                         select beb;
                string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["idname"];
                DataListBeb.DataBind();
```

With this code, if I click on all 2 B & Bs, the detail page of the `idname = 0` comes out for both of them. How can I make the other detail page of the B&B visible?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: What is the resulting URL that's used in the browser?  Did you just mean to do this?: `"~/site/DisplayBeb.aspx?idname=" + Eval("name")`

Comment: the url is 
1) http://localhost:59022/site/DisplayBeb?idname=0
2)http://localhost:59022/site/DisplayBeb?idname=1

Comment: @ysola: What exactly is the issue then?  What isn't working?  Where do you use the value from the query string in the `DisplayBeb.aspx` page?

Comment: with this code, if I click on all 2 B & B, the detail page of the idname = 0 comes out for both of them

Comment: private void fillBeb()
        {

            using (dcDataContext dc = new dcDataContext())
            {

                DataListBeb.DataSource = from beb in dc.beb
                                         select beb;
                string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["idname"];

                DataListBeb.DataBind();
            }

Comment: does anyone have any idea how to make this query string?

Comment: @ysola: After you do this: `string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["idname"];` - Where do you ever *use* that value?  It sounds like you are successfully making the query string, you just never use it for anything.

Comment: that's exactly what I said because I don't know how to use it

Comment: where and how can i use it and how is the sintax ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the query string *itself* is correct, so you're focusing on the wrong place for the problem.  You are successfully getting the query string value:

```
string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["idname"];
```

You're just not *using* that value for anything.  I suspect you probably want to use it in a `where` clause on your query:

```
string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["idname"];
DataListBeb.DataSource = from beb in dc.beb
                         where beb.name == fullname1
                         select beb;
```

or:

```
string fullname1 = Request.QueryString["idname"];
DataListBeb.DataSource = dc.beb.Where(b => b.name == fullname1);
```

Of course I don't know what your `beb` model looks like or what its properties are called, so `beb.name` was entirely a guess based on the use of `Eval("name")` above.  Simply use whatever property is appropriate in your query.

Comment: beb is the tab on db where the primary key is idname

Comment: @ysola: When you debug, what specifically is the problem?  Does `fullname1` have the value you expect?  (In the examples you have it would be something like `'0'` or `'1'`, which I wouldn't expect to be a "name" but your data model is your own business.)  Do any records in the data exist with that value in the column you're using in the query?  If the query is successfully returning zero records then the code is working, you just have a logical mistake somewhere in your understanding of your data.

Comment: the query is successfully returning zero records

Comment: @ysola: Then the code works.  You're just expecting data to be there that isn't there.  That's a separate issue.  Maybe you're putting the wrong value on the URL query string?  Maybe you're querying the wrong column in the database?

Comment: The problem is that if I click or on one b & b or on the other (at the moment there are only 2 b & B) you can only see the card of the first B&B with idname = 0

Comment: @ysola: That was the original problem, correct?  That was because you weren't using the query string value from the URL and instead were querying all records.  Presumably on your page you only show the first result.  So when you fetch all records from the table and show the first result, you will always show the first record.  Instead of querying all records, use a value from the URL's query string to filter only the record(s) you want.  This is done with a `where` clause in your database query, as demonstrated above.